# Gnuplot--Unicode characters with postscript terminal

Tags: unicode, gnuplot, unicode-string

I want to print a per mil sign (‰) with Gnuplot. I am using postscript output terminal. I tried with 'set encoding utf8', and then call the per mil sign with {u+2030}. This does not work.

I do not have pdfcairo available as an output terminal.
Below are the available terminals on my MacBook Pro.
gnuplot> print GPVAL_TERMINALS
 canvas cgm context corel dumb dxf eepic emf emtex epslatex fig hpgl latex mf mp pcl5 postscript pslatex pstex pstricks qms svg tek40xx tek410x texdraw tgif tkcanvas tpic unknown vttek x11 xlib xterm

Comment: Try to add adobeglyphnames in the "set font" command (not sure if it will help)

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain a "per mil" symbol with the postscript terminal using special character `{\275}`:

```
set term postscript enhanced
set output "out.ps"
set xlabel "{\275}"
plot x
```

[image]

Comment: @Lynn What do you mean? Special symbols can be mapped to numbers using this syntax.

Comment: Where did you get the number `\275` from?

Comment: @Lynn Just googling things can go a long way. http://www.tatsuromatsuoka.com/gnuplot/Jpn/files/OctCode.jpg Or this one: http://geophysics.eas.gatech.edu/classes/Intro_GMT/gmt_www/gmt/doc/html/GMT_Docs/node160.html